Making POST requests and Scraping JS-generated content in Python
So, to scrape the content of a page that is dynamically generated in vue-app tag, I firstly need to log-in with credentials, which is done by POST request. The problem is that for successful login, I need to provide CSRF token, which is AFAIK bond to the session, that in turn requires the client accessing the target page be the same client accessing the login page initially to get the CSRF token. Put simply, I need one client that does both login POST-request and JS-generated code scraping.
For the latter, I would typically use Selenium Web-driver, however, it does not support POST requests by default. Trying to use selenium-requests driver would not help me either, as the tokens are for some reason different (maybe because selenium-requests was a pure copy of requests and not really integrated in the selenium itself).
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import seleniumrequests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Chrome Options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Web-driver on selenium-requests
driver = seleniumrequests.Chrome(service=Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'), options=chrome_options)

# login url
login_url = 'https://example.com/login'

# target url
target_url = 'https://example.com/profile'

# csrf
driver.get(login_url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
csrf = soup.find('input', {'name':'user[_csrf_token]'}).get('value')

# payload
payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'csrf': csrf
}

# POST-query
response = driver.request('POST', login_url, data=payload)

if response.status_code == 200:
    try:
        # Open target url
        driver.get(target_url)
        page_html = driver.page_source
        print(page_html)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
else:
    print(f"Failed to login. Status code: {response.status_code}")

I also tried saving login credentials in cookies, that didn't work, and then I realized this website is not supporting cookies.
Any help appreciated.

why not login with selenium by sending keys?

@GTK Thanks, sending keys indeed helped me to avoid POST requests. But now I'm stuck on the absense of vue-app tag in my page source. The whole code is rendered normally, but the vue-app tag is replaced with 

try waiting for the page to fully load before extracting the page_source.
